# JQUERY - .html() can also view php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The following script sends data with ajax for login

I want to format the data returned by using, in essence, a session variable ($ _SESSION)

I can do it

```
 $("#login").click(function(){

username=$("#user_name").val();
password=$("#password").val();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/login.inc.php",
    data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
    success: function(msg){
      if(msg!='false')
      {
        $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
        $("#profile").html("<\?php print(\"$_SESSION['name'].\" <a href='inc\/logout.inc.php' id='logout'>Logout k2<\/a>\");\?>");
        //valori menù
        if(tipo=='1')
        {$("#admin").css('display','none')}

      }
      else
      {
            $("#add_err").html("Username o password errata");
      }
    },
    beforeSend:function()
    {
         $("#add_err").html("<img hspace='84' src='img/loading.gif' alt='Loading...'  width='32' height='32'>" )
    }
});
 return false;
```

});

especially this is possible, in this way would print the name of the user just logged. otherwise I would not know how to do

```
$("#profile").html("<\?php print(\"$_SESSION['name'].\" <a href='inc\/logout.inc.php' id='logout'>Logout k2<\/a>\");\?>");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't insert PHP code after the script has already been processed.

Either pull it in via ajax, or include the actual PHP output into your javascript.

ie, in page.php

```
   <script>
       var sessionName = '<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>';
   </script>
```

then when you need it later

```
 $("#profile").html(sessionName + " <a href=\"inc/logout.inc.php\" id=\"logout\">Logout k2</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is client-side, it simply can't execute your php code.

You have to return something (eg. the username) in the php file you use in your ajax request and use that in your JS.

See the [jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to serve the php code:

```
$("#profile").load("inc/login-header.inc.php");
```

login-header.inc.php

```
<?php
  print($_SESSION['name'] . " <a href='inc/logout.inc.php' id='logout'>Logout k2</a>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to send information back from the php script to the javascript, is by using the `msg` variable in

```
success: function(msg){
```

If you just want to send back one string, you just `echo` that one string in your php file and you will have its value in `msg`. If there are multiple variables you want to send back, you can package the result in a json object.

So assuming that everything you want to send back is contained in the php array named `$output`, you do a `echo json_encode($output);` at the end of your php script to get the whole thing in `msg`.

Answer (score 0):

that won't work, as the PHP code is never processed.

In `login.inc.php` try something like this

```
<?php
if (!loginOK()){
     echo "{login:false}";
} else {
     echo "{login:true, name:'".$_SESSION['name']."'}";

}
```

and then on the client

```
success: function(msg){
    if (msg.login){
       // stuff
    } else {
       $("#profile").html(msg.name + $('<a>').attr('href', 'logout.php').html('logout'));
    }
}
```